# How to instantiate an object which belongs to another class without importing

Tags: python, class, oop

[image]I am working on the second part of my Bank management system project in Python.
I have 4 modules created: person.py, bank_account.py, bank_card.py and main.py

I also have 3 classes created for each of the following modules: Person Class, Bank Account Class and Bank Card class.

I am being asked to create a new_card class function under Bank_Account class. To do so, I have imported (because I am allowed here) the Bank Card class into the bank_account.py module. No problem at this point. This is the code used for my new_card function within my Bank_Account class:

```
def new_card (self,card_number, month, year, cvv, pin_code):
    card1 = Bank_Card(card_number,month,year,cvv,pin_code)
    self.__bank_card = card1
    return card1
```

Where I am struggling is when the task request to create a card object in main.py. I **am not allowed to import** the *Bank Card* to *main.py* but instead I need to create the card object using the function *new_card* defined on *Bank_Account* class. When I am trying to do so by trying to create card2 in *main.py*, I cannot call the new_card function like *card2.new_card* since the Bank_Card class was not imported :(

Any ideas?

I have added a screenshot of how my code looks so far... If I do it as proposed (calling the method Bank_Account.new_card(), then I get an error saying that there are missing arguments.

I hope the picture helps you to clarify a little bit more the issue I am facing

Comment: a class method has a decorator `@classmethod` and the first argument usually is `cls` and please provide a [mre], it is unclear what is `card2` and why can't you instantiate `BankAccount` and call the `new_card` method on that class

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue. There is no problem at all using a function without in a module that doesn't import the function's dependencies.

Comment: I suggest you reread the error message - it says something entirely different than what is presented in the question. Also, please don't require volunteers to retype your code from a screenshot - provide the code (as a [mcve]!) as code formatted text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to import `Bank_Card` class in you main program as it is indirectly available in the `Bank_Account` class. From what I can understand from the question, all you need to do is import the `Bank_Account` class to the main program from "bank_account.py" module.

This is how you could achieve the same:

```
## File: "main.py"

# Import the Bank Account class from the module
from bank_account import Bank_Account

# Define the card details which will be used for creating the card
# You may provide the details inline to the method call if you want

card_number = ...
month = ...
year = ...
cvv = ...
pin_code = ...

# Create a new bank card instance by calling the `new_card` method
my_card = Bank_Account.get_card(card_number, month, year, cvv, pin_code)
```

Here, we are importing the `Bank_Account` class from `bank_account.py` module and then calling the `new_card()` method that was created on the class. This will return a new Bank Card instance which you can use as intended. Unfortunately, it will throw an error when calling `Bank_Account.get_card()` method, since `new_card` is not a static method. In order to fix that, you need to decorate the `new_card` method as a static method like so:

```
class Bank_Account:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def new_card(card_number, month, year, cvv, pin_code):
        ...
```

Note that the `self` parameter is removed from the `new_card()` method since it does not need an object of `Bank_Account` class but could instead be called directly using the class itself.

Comment: Thank you! @Melvin Abraham... sounds like a good proposal but I still having errors with my code.

Comment: @CristianA I have made a minor edit. Check it out if that helps :)